# htaccess change extension then change rest of url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to first change the extension, then change the rest of the URL, but can't figure out how.

This is what i'm trying right now:

```
RewriteRule ^brands/living(.*)\.html$ /maerker/bolig/$1.htm [PT] <- Not working
RewriteRule ^brands/living/oldcat(.*)$ /maerker/bolig/newcat$1 [L,R=301] <- Works as intented
```

The first line should change the extension then the second line should  change the rest of the URL, but it doesn't work.

The result I want is:

```
www.domain.com/brands/living/oldcat/product.html
```

Changes to:

```
www.domain.com/maerker/bolig/newcat/product.htm
```

Comment: If it's working as intended, then what's the problem?

Comment: The first line should change the extension then the second line should  change the rest of the URL, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand if all you want is the product then why not just use:

```
RewriteRule ^brands/living/oldcat/(.*)\.html$ /maerker/bolig/newcat/$1.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

The first rule doesn't just change the extension, it changes the URI as well, this causes the second rule to not match. If you want 2 rules, one to change the extension and the other to change the URI, then try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.htm [PT]   
RewriteRule ^brands/living/oldcat(.*)$ /maerker/bolig/newcat$1 [L,R=301]
```